# Ansible : evaluate variable inside a variable with register

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

I have a task where i need to evaluate a variable attribute , where the name is already a vaiable.

**here is the scenario :**

i'm executing a **shell** command ( `docker ps` ) and i'm registering the output in a variable , **where the name is already dynamic**:

```
- name : Display running containers for {{apiType}}
  shell: docker ps
  register: docker_containers_{{apiType}}
  when:
    - '"containers" in type'
```

no i want to display the content of that ouput and not only the string itself , so i need to do something like this:

```
- name: Display running containers for {{apiType}}
  debug:
   msg: {{docker_containers_{{apiType}}.stdout}}
  when:
    - '"containers" in type'
```

of course , this  :   `{{docker_containers_{{apiType}}.stdout}}` 
is syntaxically refused

i ve tried this : `{{docker_containers_[apiType].stdout}}`

but it fails.

**Suggestions?**

Comment: Is there any real reason to register variable with dynamic name like `docker_containers_{{apiType}}`?

Comment: You can't. Add a [separate task to set the fact](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38143647/2947502).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [FAQ](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-access-a-variable-name-programmatically). You can build a string and use that to index the `hostvars` for your current host:

```
- name: Display running containers for {{apiType}}
  debug:
   msg: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['docker_containers_' + apiType].stdout}}"
  when:
    - '"containers" in type'
```

...this assumes that your `docker_containers_...` variable is a host fact, rather than, say, something set via `group_vars` or a `vars` stanza in your playbook.

Here's a runnable example:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    apiType: foo

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        docker_containers_foo:
          stdout: "this is foo"
    - set_fact:
        docker_containers_bar:
          stdout: "this is bar"

    - name: Display running containers for {{apiType}}
      debug:
        msg: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['docker_containers_' + apiType].stdout}}"
```