# In Ansible how do you change a existing dictionary/hash values using a variable for the key

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

As the title suggest i want to loop over an existing dictionary and change some values, based on the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38143647/set-fact-with-dynamic-key-name-in-ansible) i came up with the code below but it doesn't work as the values are unchanged in the second debug call, I'm thinking it is because in the other question they are creating a new dictionary from scratch, but I've also tried it without the outer curly bracket which i would have thought would have caused it to change the existing value.

```
- set_fact:
  uber_dict:
    a_dict:
      some_key: "abc"
      another_key: "def"
    b_dict:
      some_key: "123"
      another_key: "456"

- debug: var="uber_dict"

- set_fact: "{ uber_dict['{{ item }}']['some_key'] : 'xyz' }"
  with_items: "{{ uber_dict }}"

- debug: var="uber_dict"
```

Comment: You cannot. Define a whole new `uber_dict`.

Comment: @techraf I knew you couldn't merge hash's passed in (although i think there is a option now to do that) but i didn't think that applied altering them too, thought of it just after posting but maybe i could do something with the [combine](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries) filter but i suspect it will be pretty ugly

Comment: Whatever you do, you must ...read my first comment.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can not **change** existing variable, but you can register new one with the same name.

Check this example:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    uber_dict:
      a_dict:
        some_key: "abc"
        another_key: "def"
      b_dict:
        some_key: "123"
        another_key: "456"
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        uber_dict: "{{ uber_dict | combine(new_item, recursive=true) }}"
      vars:
        new_item: "{ '{{ item.key }}': { 'some_key': 'some_value' } }"
      with_dict: "{{ uber_dict }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ uber_dict }}"
```

Result:

```json
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "a_dict": {
            "another_key": "def",
            "some_key": "some_value"
        },
        "b_dict": {
            "another_key": "456",
            "some_key": "some_value"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: had just be trying out the same thing, works perfectly for my use thanks.

Comment: Does this still work? I'm having the same issue, but using the above solution I seem to get an "ansible_facts" dictionary which contains my new dictionary, (i.e. it has the updated keys) but when I print my dictionary afterwards it returns as the original version (i.e. the original key-value pairs)

Comment: How can you do that if uber_dict is a list please ?

Comment: i know it is an old question but i have similar problem and no answers on my question. What do we do if the values are nested and you need to change only them? With this approach i get overwritten target key, instead of only updated different values?