# Writing to a particular cell in csv file from Ansible

Tags: csv, module, ansible, lookup

I'm trying to find if any option to write to a particular cell in CSV file from Ansible. I can use Ansible lookup plugin type "csvfile" to lookup for a value in the csv file but I need to add text to that file. Consider below example:

```
empID,name,mark
111,user1
112,user2
113,user3
```

I need to add the mark for each user, running the playbook should prompt for the empID and marks:

```
---
- name: Update data
  hosts: localhost
  vars_prompt:
    - name: empid
      prompt: EMP_ID
      private: no
    - name: marks
      prompt: MARKS
      private: no
  tasks:
    - name: Lookup
      debug:
        msg: "{{ lookup('csvfile', '{{ empid }} file=data.csv delimiter=, col=2') }}"
```

Need help to write to CSV file column C rows 1,2,3....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As **@mdaniel** mentioned, there's no out-of-box `write_csv` module in Ansible. Without creating your own module, the only workaround I can think of is the following:

1. You read in the CSV file with `read_csv` module and register the data table as a dictionary variable.
2. You add the new values to the dict variable recursively with the key "mark". (Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48825583/in-ansible-how-do-you-change-a-existing-dictionary-hash-values-using-a-variable) for modifying values in dict variable)
3. You loop over the dict variable and output each line to a new file with the `lineinfile` module. The file can be created with`.csv` extension, and in each line, the values are separated with delimiters (`,` or `;`).

Here is an example:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - name: Read from CSV file
      community.general.read_csv:
        path: data.csv
        key: empID
        delimiter: ','
      register: response
    - name: Create a dict variable from the CSV file
      set_fact:
        data_dict: "{{  response.dict  }}"
    - name: Update values in dictionary recursively
      set_fact:
        data_dict: "{{ data_dict | combine(new_item, recursive=true) }}"
      vars:
        new_item: "{ '{{ item.key }}': { 'mark': 'some_value' } }"
      with_dict: "{{ data_dict }}"
    - name: Debug
      debug:
        msg: "{{  data_dict  }}"
    - name: Save ddata_dict headers to a new CSV file
      lineinfile:
        path: new_data.csv
        line: empID,name,mark
        create: yes
    - name: Save data_dict values to a new CSV file
      lineinfile:
        path: new_data.csv
        line: "{{ item.value.empID }},{{ item.value.name }},{{ item.value.mark }}"
      loop: "{{ data_dict | dict2items }}"
```

And the outputted CSV file is:

```
empID,name,mark
111,user1,some_value
112,user2,some_value
113,user3,some_value
```

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't appear to be a provided `write_csv` mechanism in ansible, partially because ansible is not a general purpose computing platform. However, you can easily [write your own module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/3/dev_guide/developing_locally.html) which behaves as you wish, or you may be able to find an existing one out in [ansible galaxy](https://galaxy.ansible.com/search?deprecated=false&keywords=csv&order_by=-relevance&page=1)