# Ansible: How to update or change a value in a nested dictionary from a REST API call?

Tags: dictionary, ansible, nested

I had search in a few forums including this one, but none of them seems to be able to provide the solution for me. In the playbook, I am doing a call via `uri` module that registers a variable: `result`.

`result.json` looks like this

```json
{
"global_api_concurrency_limit": 199,
"client_api_rate_limit": 100,
"client_api_concurrency_limit": 40,
"connection_timeout": 30,
"redirect_host": "",
"protocol_versions": [
{"enabled": true, "name": "TLSv1.1"},
{"enabled": true, "name": "TLSv1.2"}
]
}
```

I checked via `result.json | type_debug` and says its a dictionary.

I want to update property to `"enabled": false` where `"name": "TLSv1.1"`.

Noting that `false` is not quoted in the JSON. So my idea is to either create a new dict or update the same dict. But I am stuck how I can update only that value.

I attempted the below tasks, but it obviously didn't work.

```yaml
  - name: Call NSXT
    vars:
      api: "/api/v1/cluster/api-service"
    ansible.builtin.uri:
      url: "https://server01{{ api }}"
      user: user1
      password: pwd1
      method: GET
      force_basic_auth: true
      validate_certs: false
      headers:
        Content-Type: application/json
    register: result

  - set_fact:
      newdic: "{{ (newdic | d([])) | combine(new_item, recursive=True) }}"
    with_dict: "{{ result.json }}"
    vars:
      new_item: {'enabled': false}
    when: item.protocol_versions.name == 'TLSv1.1'
```

Any advise how to improve this? (*Note: I don't want to install `jmespath` for JSON queries, because of company restrictions*)

I couldn't figure out how I can only update one value with that nested dictionary?

Comment: According your description I wonder if you could use [`update_fact` module – Update currently set facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/utils/update_fact_module.html)?

Answer (score 1):

According your description I wonder if you could use the [update_fact module – Update currently set facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/utils/update_fact_module.html)? It is intended for updating variables and one of the documented [Examples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/utils/update_fact_module.html#examples) seems to be similar to yours.

Based on your provided sample data, a minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - include_vars:
      file: result.json
      name: result

  - ansible.utils.update_fact:
      updates:
        - path: result.protocol_versions[0]
          value: {"enabled": false, "name": "TLSv1.1"}
    register: updated

  - debug:
      var: updated
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] *************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  updated:
    changed: true
    failed: false
    result:
      client_api_concurrency_limit: 40
      client_api_rate_limit: 100
      connection_timeout: 30
      global_api_concurrency_limit: 199
      protocol_versions:
      - enabled: false
        name: TLSv1.1
      - enabled: true
        name: TLSv1.2
      redirect_host: ''
```

If it is not clear if the `result.protocol_versions` will contain the correct versions, of if the order is not clear, it is also possible to define the desired state of the configuration.

```yaml
  - ansible.utils.update_fact:
      updates:
        - path: result.protocol_versions
          value: [{"enabled": false, "name": "TLSv1.1"}, {"enabled": true, "name": "TLSv1.2"}]
    register: updated
```

Please take note that even if using [`update_fact` module – Update currently set facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/utils/update_fact_module.html)

> *Variables are not modified in place, instead they are returned by the module.*

and [that is the expected behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48825995/6771046).

Comment: Thanks, but the danger is that this may not be portable. The code should not expect TLSv1.1 or TLSv1.2 only nor expect them to be ordered in the current way (so [0] position may not work) in future it is possible to have TLSv1.3 and this won't work. What I am looking for is code that will just look for TLSv1.1 and modify that and leave the rest alone. That is, I don't need to konw about future versions.

Comment: "_The code should not expect TLSv1.1 or TLSv1.2 only nor expect them to be ordered in the current way_", But isn't that what the second example shows?

Comment: Correct, but its not generic enough. If my result now also has {"enabled": true, "name": "TLSv1.3"}. The update will remove this row. What I want is a generic way without knowing any other values just to update enabled to false from TLSv1.1.

Comment: Right, as far as I understand such is called configuration management and desired state configuration and one would just define the desired state `[{"enabled": false, "name": "TLSv1.1"}, {"enabled": true, "name": "TLSv1.2"}, {"enabled": true, "name": "TLSv1.3"}]`.

Comment: I agree, but I think my exercise is also to learn how to use ansible/jija/python logic to update a single value based on a nested dictionary such as this, also such logic can be useful else where to update variables or dictionaries not just for config mgmt. There don't seem to be a simple solution yet. I have explored with_dict, with_subelements, etc, but I could not figure out how they work for what I want to go

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found the answer, this will update just the row with name=TLSv1.1

```
  - ansible.utils.update_fact:
      updates:
        - path: "result.json.protocol_versions[{{item}}].enabled"
          value: false
    loop: "{{ range(result.json.protocol_versions|length) }}"
    when: result.json.protocol_versions[{{item}}].name == "TLSv1.1"
    register: updated
```