# Ansible variable value as variable name

Tags: ansible

I want to make a variable named as value of _id.
And it seems to be working fine (tested on _id value i know), except I have no clue how to deal with it via _id field.

```
- name: Set fact
  set_fact: 
    "{{_id}}": "{{ _name }}"
```

Comment: it has already been answered at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38143647/set-fact-with-dynamic-key-name-in-ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38143647/set-fact-with-dynamic-key-name-in-ansible)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the `set_fact` module, you just have to change your syntax up a bit to reference the metadata in a dictionary for the variable.

```
- set_fact: {"{{ item.key }}":"{{ item.val }}"}
  loop: "{{ item }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: item
```

Let me know if you have any questions or need any additional help. Happy to assist if I can. Ansible is fun. :)